# fire an onchange event in select form control in drupal 7 forms api

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, form-api, form-control

I have a select form control in Drupal 7. How to call a function to whenever onchange event fires.

This is my select form control code:

```
$form['id']['signature'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',       
    '#options' => array(
        0 => t('Browse...'),
        1 => t('Sign...'),
        2 => t('Clear...'),        
    ),       
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with '#attibutes'.
eg.

```
$form['id']['signature']['#attributes'] = array('onchange' => array('myFunction()'))
```

Though I never like adding event attributes to html tags, so you could also probably do it by adding inline (or extenal) javascript to the form with a behavior like this:

```
$form['id']['signature'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',       
    '#options' => array(
        0 => t('Browse...'),
        1 => t('Sign...'),
        2 => t('Clear...'),        
    ),
    '#attributes' => array(
        'id' => array('signature-goes-here'),
    ),
);
$form['id']['signature']['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'data' => "
Drupal.behaviors.signature = function (context) {
  $('#signature-goes-here', context).change(function () {
    // Do stuff here.
  });
}
",
    'type' => 'inline',
);
```

But if you wanted to fire ajax when this form item changes, you would probably use the Drupal form api functionality.